# least absolute deviation regression's coefficient significance levels

Tags: r, regression, outliers, descriptive-statistics

When I run the least absolute deviation regression using command 'lad' from the 'L1pack' package, I get the following result but cannot determine the significance levels for each coefficients.

```
 Call:
 lad(formula = co[, 12] ~ co[, 2] + co[, 3] + co[, 5] + 
     co[, 7] + co[, 8] + co[, 9] + co[, 11] + co[, 2] * 
     co[, 11])
 Converged in 14 iterations

 Coefficients:
           (Intercept)            co[, 2]            co[, 3] 
              12.6123              -0.4472              -0.0528 
            co[, 5]               co[, 7]            co[, 8] 
              -0.1073               0.0051               0.0004 
            co[, 9]               co[, 11]           co[, 2]:co[, 11] 
              -9.6531              -0.9975               0.2303 

 Degrees of freedom: 101 total; 92 residual
 Scale estimate: 2.675847
```

Is there a way to figure out some general regression statistics like t-test, f-test, R square, etc. from this 'lad' regression? The 'summary' command does not seem to give out these as in the linear regression command 'lm'.

I tried using robust regression 'rlm' in 'MASS' package and see that I get required summary statistics for coefficients and their significances. However, I still do not get values for f-test, R square or so.

How about using this 'rlm' to resolve the outlier problem?

Besides, what methods would be appropriate for getting the f-test and R square values which I suppose cannot simply bring from simple linear regression 'lm' summary result?

Answer (score 3):

There's not actually a t-test, because the estimate divided by its standard error doesn't have a t-distribution. Similar for an F-test.

Being a maximum likelihood estimate, there would be an asymptotic z-test, or an asymptotic chi-square test.

[There's the possibility of using some resampling-based tests as well, permutation tests or bootstrapping. You could also use L1pack's ability to simulate from L1 models to do a parametric bootstrap.]

You could compute something like an $R^2$ but it doesn't quite make sense because you're not computing something that tries to maximize that; it might make more sense to compute some analogous statistic, but $R^2$ has a number of properties and it depends on which things you try to carry over and which you don't.

[I note that quantreg::rq (which by default does L1 regression) will give an interval for the coefficients; this allows for a test (since you can see if the interval includes 0). There are also some other testing options in that package]

Comment: Thanks but then how do people usually report the LAD regression results if one cannot show t-test, f-test, R square, etc. to check the coefficients and overall model's validity? How about using these values directly from the ones produced using simple linear regression with the same data?

Comment: If this question is not easy to answer, then probably the fundamental question may be better to approach, I suppose. If I want to run the regression by adjusting it with outliers, what is the best way to do this except simply removing the outliers and want to see the full report of the regression analysis for interpretations?

Comment: I tried using robust regression 'rlm' in 'MASS' package and see that I get required summary statistics for coefficients and their significances. However, I still do not get values for f-test, R square or so. How about using this 'rlm' to resolve the outlier problem? Besides, what methods do you think would be appropriate for getting the f-test and R square values which I suppose cannot simply bring from simple linear regression 'lm' summary result?

Comment: Just because `rlm` will *print* a t-value doesn't mean the t-value it gives you has a t-distribution (and it doesn't, though it is reasonably close to the asymptotic normal distribution across a variety of situations).  The problem is that t- and F-distributions for test statistics ultimately rely on the very normality you are no longer willing to assume. As I have already said, you can test coefficients or the overall model, and in some cases groups of coefficients, in any of several potential ways, but small-sample normal theory tests don't just plug into things that aren't normal. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... You can sometimes get asymptotic approximations (sort-of t-like statistics that will go asymptotically to a normal and sort-of F-like statistics that go asymptotically to a chi-square ... these are mentioned already in my post). If something will give you a coefficient and a standard error you can call the calculated result a "t-ratio" if you like (as `rlm` has done) but it won't have a t-distribution and you'll have to see how it behaves in situations like the one you're interested in -- it may work okay for some estimators with some particular standard error calculations. ... ctd

Comment: Thanks but when I simply divide the coefficient by the produced standard error I get the t-test values straight away which I suppose to be correct that compares with zero.

Comment: ctd ... But even if not, there are other ways to get tests that can give you p-values (and again these are mentioned in my post).

Comment: For the f-test, I found that f.robftest command from sfsmisc library gives out the f-test value for rlm?

Comment: Eric I don't even understand what you're asking there. You can divide an estimated coefficient by an estimated standard error that some programs produce and you can call the ratio a "t-ratio" if you choose but calling it it that doesn't make it have a t-distribution.. Would you mind not spamming me with more and more R packages and functions (all of which are off topic the way you ask about them) and try to understand what I am spending more and more of my time explaining to you.

Comment: If a t-statistic isn't t-distributed, it's somewhat misleading to call it "t" (and in some cases potentially quite misleading). You have to be very careful about interpreting it. If `rlm` gives you a t-statistic of 1.985 on a coefficient, what does that mean? What are you using that to do?

Comment: So it is (coefficient - zero)/standard error = t-test value. This is comparing the coefficient from zero to find whether it is significantly different from zero or not. I am simply using this to claim how much the coefficients are significantly different from zero.

Comment: HOW are you deciding significance.

Comment: By the way, is it correct to use "f.robftest" command to get the f-test value for the rlm regression?

Comment: By figuring out whether it is significantly different from zero. That's it.

Comment: You repeat yourself. HOW are you doing that. As I said say you have t=1.985. What do you do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58287/discussion-between-glen-b-and-eric).

Comment: I suppose you don't have to worry about the t-test stuff. That depends on what confidence level I choose. For instance if I choose 5%, then the value you mentioned may not be enough to claim it to be significant at the 5% level depending on the degrees of freedom I have. Please just check the f-test one that I mentioned.

Comment: I find the command called f.robftest from the sfsmisc package which gives out the f-test result. Can I use this result to define the f-test statistics for rlm? Also, I seem to get R square by simply inputting the values into the R square mathematical formula like 1 - sum(residuals(rlm(y~x))^2)/sum((y-mean(y))^2).For t-test values to check the significance of the coefficients, I get the t-test values from summary(rlm(y~x)) that I compare with the t-values from 95% confidence levels or so. Can I use these methods?